# Swift functional way to get single item from a subarray

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I have the following function (example), which I would like to write in a functional way:

```
func passengerForId(_ id: Int) -> Passenger?
{
    for car in cars
    {
        for passenger in car.passengers
        {
            if passenger.id == id
            {
                return passenger
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

What would be the best way?

I've tried the following:

```
func passengerForId(_ id: Int) -> Passenger?
{
    return cars.first(where: { $0.passengers.contains(where: { $0.id == id } ) })
}
```

However, that obviously returns the car containing the requested passenger, and not the passenger itself.

Another option would something like:

```
func passengerForId(_ id: Int) -> Passenger?
{
    let passengers = cars.flatMap { car in car.passengers }
    return passengers.first(where: { $0.id == id })
}
```

or

```
func passengerForId(_ id: Int) -> Passenger?
{
    return cars.flatMap { car in car.passsengers.filter { $0.id == id }}.first
}
```

However, that seems less efficient than the original, as it will loop over  all the areas.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: the last example is as functional as you can get

Comment: you can consider storing passengers in a separate array and each passenger has reference to its car, car on the other hand only has `passengerIds = [1, 2, 3..]`. On the other hand, if you have less then thousands of cars - any way is fine and won't cost much time

Comment: Your last one is good. Just add `lazy`: `cars.lazy.flatMap(...` and it won’t create intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a (lazy) flattened collection of all passengers, and pick
the first matching one:

```
func passengerForId(_ id: Int) -> Passenger? {
    return cars.lazy.flatMap({ $0.passengers }).first(where: { $0.id == id } )
}
```

Comment: Heh; yeah, I just rewrote mine this way because it's much cleaner…

Comment: @RobNapier: Sorry, I hadn't seen your new version :)

Comment: That's because you beat me to it :D

Comment: Nice! Never knew 'lazy' could be used in such a way. Thanks for the quick response!